# Find the sum of the following inﬁnite series:

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the following inﬁnite series:

$$\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1.4}{5.10}+\frac{1.4.7}{5.10.15}- ...$$

---

stuck on this problem.seek your help